# MongoDB $in with $and Query

Tags: java, mongodb

Is this type of query possible?

I need to query the database for data for a specified date for a set of specified stocks. So the data needs to have "this" date and be one of "these" symbols.

I have the following code:

```
public void findDateStockSet(String date, ArrayList<String> symbolSet) throws UnknownHostException {
    this.stocks = this.getCollectionFromDB();
    BasicDBObject objectToFind = new BasicDBObject();
    List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("date", date));
    obj.add(new BasicDBObject("symbol", new BasicDBObject("$in", symbolSet)));
    objectToFind.put("$and", obj);


    DBCursor cursor = this.stocks.find(objectToFind);

    System.out.println("Finding Stocks");
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This always comes up null. Can someone explain how to make a query like this work?

Comment: Could you put an example of your documents?

Comment: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51dc5fc203646b5aa5ffaed2"} , "date" : "20100223" , "symbol" : "aapl" , "open" : "199.91" , "high" : "201.33" , "low" : "195.71" , "close" : "197.059" , "volume" : "205468"}

Comment: I just thought I should confess I was entering a wrong date in the search query. That's why I was getting a null. The above code works as well as Miguel's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use $and operator, just build the query as the json below:

```
{ "date" : "20100223", "symbol" : { $in : [ "appl", "goog" ] } }
```

I like to use `BasicDBObjectBuilder` util class to build DBObjects. So your query will be:

```
DBObject query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
    .add("date", date)
    .push("symbol")
        .add("$in", symbolSet)
    .get();
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel! That's an easy way to create a query and it worked perfectly!